# Using default dictionaries problem (python)

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, resourcedictionary

I have a slightly weird input of data that is in this format:

```
data = { 'sensor1': {'units': 'x', 'values': [{'time': 17:00, 'value': 10},
                                       {'time': 17:10, 'value': 12}, 
                                       {'time': 17:20, 'value' :7}, ...]}
  'sensor2': {'units': 'x', 'values': [{'time': 17:00, 'value': 9},
                                       {'time': 17:20, 'value': 11}, ...]}
}

And I want to collect the output to look like:

{'17:00': [10,9], '17:10': [12,], '17:20': [7,11], ... }
```

So the keys are the unique timestamps (ordered) and the values are a list of the values of each sensor, in order they come in the original dictionary. If there is no value for the timestamp in one sensor, it is just left as an empty element ''. I know I might need to use defaultdict but I've not had any success.

e.g.

```
    s = [('yellow', 1), ('blue', 2), ('yellow', 3), ('blue', 4), ('red', 1)]
    d = defaultdict(list)
        for k, v in s:
            d[k].append(v)
   
    sorted(d.items())
    [('blue', [2, 4]), ('red', [1]), ('yellow', [1, 3])]
```

```
    d = defaultdict(default_factory=list)
    values_list = data.values()
    for item in values_list:
        for k, v in item['values']:
            d[k].append(v)

    result = sorted(d.items())
```

Encounters key error as each item in values_list is not a tuple but a dict.

Comment: *"If there is no value for the timestamp in one sensor, it is just left as an empty element ''."* This sentence is confusing. Note that `[12,]` is exactly equivalent to `[12]` in python, it is a list with a single element (and no way to know if this element came from the first or the second sensor). Instead you might want `[12, None]` or `[None, 12]` to explicitly mark a missing element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `dict` in this way:

```
data = {'sensor1': {'units': 'x', 'values': [{'time': '17:00', 'value': 10},
                                             {'time': '17:10', 'value': 12},
                                             {'time': '17:20', 'value': 7},
                                             ]},
        'sensor2': {'units': 'x', 'values': [{'time': '17:00', 'value': 9},
                                             {'time': '17:20', 'value': 11},
                                             ]}
        }

d = {}
for item in data.values():
    for pair in item['values']:
        if pair["time"] in d:
            d[pair["time"]].append(pair["value"])
        else:
            d[pair["time"]] = [pair["value"]]

result = sorted(d.items())
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[('17:00', [10, 9]), ('17:10', [12]), ('17:20', [7, 11])]
```

Using `defaultdict` [`defaultdict` example with `list` in Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples) :

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = {'sensor1': {'units': 'x', 'values': [{'time': '17:00', 'value': 10},
                                             {'time': '17:10', 'value': 12},
                                             {'time': '17:20', 'value': 7},
                                             ]},
        'sensor2': {'units': 'x', 'values': [{'time': '17:00', 'value': 9},
                                             {'time': '17:20', 'value': 11},
                                             ]}
        }

d = defaultdict(list)
for item in data.values():
    for pair in item['values']:
        d[pair["time"]].append(pair["value"])
result = sorted(d.items())
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[('17:00', [10, 9]), ('17:10', [12]), ('17:20', [7, 11])]
```

Comment: This is now linked to my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74564045/python-nested-dictionaries-to-csv
I was hoping to use the answer for this defaultdict in that solution but I couldn't figure it...

Comment: @Stef thanks for identifying this. Updated the code.